# Wordpress homepage not going to index.php

Tags: wordpress

I will apologise to start with in that I am a graphic designer who does some coding. I have designed a wordpress site for a client and it is up and working.
I want to change the page names to their proper titles e.g. about. I know how to do that using permalink but it seems the person who set up the server did something weird with setting the domain. If I change the links to page names I get a loop on the homepage where the browser can't find index.php. If I set the permalink to default it works but the homepage is at www.ctcontracts.co.uk/ctcontracts/. This is the folder that wordpress is installed in.

I'm pretty sure I've done something stupid but could do with the help on this.

Jon

---

here's the one in root

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

RewriteEngine on

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from all


order deny,allow
deny from all

AuthName ctcontracts.co.uk

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ctcontracts.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ctcontracts.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.ctcontracts.co.uk/ctcontracts/index.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ctcontracts.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ctcontracts.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^gallery.html$ "http://www.ctcontract\ s.co.uk/ctcontracts/i\ ndex.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ctcontracts.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ctcontracts.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^ctgallery.html$ "http://www.ctcontract\ s.co.uk/ctcontracts/i\ ndex.php" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ctcontracts.co.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ctcontracts.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^contact.html$ "http://www.ctcontracts.co.uk/ctcontracts/index.php/contacts" [R=301,L]

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess` to create SEO-friendly URLs?

Answer (score 0):

What does your .htaccess look like? Should be something like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ctcontracts/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /ctcontracts/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: you should ask questions in comment section.

Comment: Cannot comment, *< 50 reputation* @JenisPatel

Comment: Hi sorry to be a pain. Where would I find that in the file manager?

Comment: @JonSaunders at the root of your `public_html` or `www` folder

Comment: there seem to be two. One in the root of the public_html folder and another in the ctcontracts folder

Comment: Sorry, the one in the `ctcontracts` folder is the one you should check

Comment: The one in the ctcontract folder just has begin wordpress and end wordpress

Comment: Try paste the code I posted above and see if that changes anything. Backup that `.htacess` file first.

Comment: which file should I paste it into

Comment: there are 2. One in the root and one in the wordpress folder

Comment: the one in the wordpress folder which I understand is called `ctcontracts`, edit the `.htaccess` file in that folder

Comment: That didn't work. i think the one I posted earlier that is in the root of the directory is causing the problem

Comment: What is in the root of the domain. It appears to be redirecting to the subfolder i.e. your wordpress installation? Why not just have the wp in root then? Any files apart from the `.htaccess` in the root folder?

Comment: Hi there's a folder called htpass. So if I moved everything out of the wordpress folder into the root it should work? It seems the home page directs to the subfolder automatically.

Comment: Ideally yes that would be a solution. Not sure how clued up you are on wordpress migrations but removing the `.htaccess` that is causing problems from root and moving your installation to root would solve all your problems.

Comment: Ok should be able to do that. It was installed from cpanel wordpress install. At the worst I can always remover everything from public html and start again

Answer (score 0):

You can find the .htaccess inside the "ctcontracts" folder. In your .htaccess if you have something like

```
RewriteBase /
```

replace it with

```
RewriteBase /ctcontracts/
```